# BigQuery: TABLE_QUERY but columns differ between tables

Tags: google-bigquery

We are loading csv files into BigQuery. Each file will create a separate table.

When we select from these tables, we do this mostly with a table query liek so:

```
SELECT foo, bar
FROM TABLE_QUERY(name_stub,'table_id CONTAINS "_something" and msec_to_timestamp(creation_time) > date_add(current_timestamp(), -90, "day")'));
```

Now we have added new fields to the newer files. So instead of just having fields "foo" and "bar" we now additionally have "baz".

When I run the following query, I get the error, that the field "baz" does not exists on one of the older tables.

```
SELECT foo, bar, baz
FROM TABLE_QUERY(name_stub,'table_id CONTAINS "_something" and msec_to_timestamp(creation_time) > date_add(current_timestamp(), -90, "day")'));
```

Is there a way to select "baz" and just have a default value for tables that don't have the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: This issue has been addressed.

BigQuery now supports TABLE_DATE_RANGE over tables where a subset of the tables have a wider schema. The missing columns should appear as NULL in the tables where the column is missing.

https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=439

Comment: great news! example in above link is quite simplified - does this cover records, repeated, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Adding new columns to a table is possible (all historic data will automatically have NULLs), but you are creating new table every day - and TABLE_QUERY is just a shortcut syntax for UNION.
The only idea I have is to create a view which will add column "baz" to the old tables. Then you should be able to use TABLE_QUERY across such views and newer tables.

Comment: very well, i guess the cleanest approach would be to create views, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The workaround solution for this is stated in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276601/bigquery-if-field-exists-then).

In my case it would have been:

```
SELECT foo, bar, coalesce(baz,0)
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mydataset.le_table,<beginning of time>,<day before column add>),
     TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mydataset.le_table,<day of column add>,<today>)
```