# bigquery query first available column

Tags: google-bigquery

This is similar to this topic here: [BigQuery IF field exists THEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276601/bigquery-if-field-exists-then?lq=1)

However, we are only querying from one table, so the table will only have either column A or column B. We found that if you query 2 tables, where one has column A and another has column B, then the below function would work,
but with our use case, we only want to query one table and we don't know which column exists or contains the data. We want to query the first column that exists and contains data.

```
            --This query works
            SELECT user_id,COALESCE(devices.A, B)
            FROM mytable1,
            mytable2
            limit 100

            -- This query does not work
            SELECT user_id,COALESCE(devices.A, B)
            FROM mytable1
            limit 100
```

The error message that we got was
Query Failed
Error: Field 'devices.A' not found in table 'mytable1'; did you mean 'devices.fieldthatexists'?

Answer (score 0):

below is direction for quick workaround

```
-- This query does not work
SELECT user_id,COALESCE(A, B)
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS user_id, 1 AS C
) AS mytable1
LIMIT 100
```

error message is `Error: Field 'A' not found; did you mean 'C'?`

```
-- This query will work
SELECT user_id,COALESCE(A, B)
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS user_id, 1 AS C
) AS mytable1,
(SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B) AS faketable
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 100
```

the idea of workaround is to supply fake table with just one row that "compensate" missing fields with then eliminating this respective fake row in WHERE clause

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the work around! Does this mean there is no other possible way? The query I have here is a simplified version of the actual query which is over 100 lines of production code and it would be great if there was a cleaner way of getting this done.

Comment: I think referencing non-existing columns will raise error. so somehow you need to "fake" system to think they are part of schema. the workaround in my answer does this. based on your simplified example and limited exposure of reallife usecase - this is the best I can think of. but you can wait for other responses