# Bigquery If field exists

Tags: google-bigquery

Short: Is there a way to query in BQ fields that don't exist, receiving nulls for these fields?

I have almost the same issue that
[BigQuery IF field exists THEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276601/bigquery-if-field-exists-then) but sometimes my APIs can query tables were there are not some particular fields (historic tables) and this approach fails because it needs a table with that field:

```
SELECT a, b, c, COALESCE(my_field, 0) as my_field
FROM
(SELECT * FROM <somewhere w/o my_field>),
(SELECT * FROM <somewhere with my_field>)
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
SELECT IFEXISTS(a, NULL) as the-field
FROM <somewhere w/o my_field>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's assume your table has x and y fields only!
So below query will perfectly work

```
SELECT x, y FROM YourTable
```

But below one will fail because of non-existing field z

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM YourTable
```

The way to address this is as below

```
#legacySQL
SELECT x, y, COALESCE(z, 0) as z
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM YourTable),
(SELECT true AS fake, NULL as z)
WHERE fake IS NULL
```

> EDIT: added explicit `#legacySQL` to not to confuse those who is trying to apply this exact approach to Standard SQL :o)

Comment: Does anybody knows why does that works? But thanks for the trick, we needed exactly that!

Comment: @Mikhail If the column exists and then I apply your above query it says Column Name is ambiguous. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @phaigeim - Feel free to post your specific question with all details - so we will be able to answer

Answer (score 7):

This can be done by using a script:

```sql
DECLARE my_field STRING;
SET my_field  = "default";
-- my_field falls back to "default" if there is no such column in my_table
SELECT my_field FROM my_table;
```

Comment: This approach worked for me when I needed my script to work with both old and new tables. A slight improvement is that the default value can be declared directly like this: 
`DECLARE my_field STRING DEFAULT "default"; `

Answer (score 4):

Like @phaigeim, I wasn't able to use Mikhail's answer in 2019 - I got "Column name z is ambiguous".

I wound up using the [BigQuery Information Schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view) tables to check if the column exists, and otherwise do `SELECT NULL as z`. I did this in `dbt` using a jinja macro since I couldn't figure out a way to do it in straight SQL. That restricts its applicability, but it may be an option in some use cases.

Comment: As FYI! At a time of that answer (2016) - BigQuery Standard SQL was in GA for just about 2 weeks - thus the answer was given for Legacy SQL!

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: It would be really nice if you could share your dbt macro!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue recently.  Apparently [bigquery has exception handling](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#beginexception) so you could do

```sql
BEGIN
  SELECT a, b FROM your_table;
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
  SELECT a, NULL AS b FROM your_table;
END
```

assuming column `a` is guaranteed to exist, but `b` might not.