# BigQuery - IF field EXISTS; in standard SQL dialect

Tags: google-bigquery

In *legacy SQL* it is possible to return the value of the field `z` or a default value if `z` is not a field in the table. This can be done with the following code (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40096552/4432148)):

```
#legacySQL
SELECT x, y, COALESCE(z, 0) as z
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM YourTable),
(SELECT true AS fake, NULL as z)
WHERE fake IS NULL
```

Is there any similar way with *standard SQL*?

Comment: I user COALESCE in standard SQL in BigQuery, and there is no problem.
What is your issue?

Comment: i think in Standard SQL, the direction is to use `Scripting` with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view to identify if particular column exists in the table and then branch your logic depends on outcome of that check. should be fairly simple :o)

Comment: @MaryamAbdoli - COALESCE is not the issue. Standard SQL won't allow `z` because its origin is ambiguous.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - thanks, I am aware that this can be solved with scripting, but I would prefer it as a SELECT-statement so that I can use it in our existing View-deployment-pipeline (which only accepts standard SQL due to its API setting).

Comment: I check the above query in the BigQuery console. If you remove `#legacySql,` there is no syntax error in the query, but the output is none(and its because of `fake`), so please add an example to your question to better understand about the problem.

Comment: @MaryamAbdoli yes, when `z` is not present in the table everything is fine. But standard SQL will throw an error if the table contains the field `z` and its original value should remain. In legacy SQL it works, in standard not.