# Wildcard tables and differences in table columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am try to use BigQuery to `JOIN` over a range of tables using `Wildcard Tables`.

The query works when all tables matched by the wildcard have the column `fooid` (`bar*.fooid`).  However this column is a recent addition and when the table wildcard matches tables where the field does not exist the query fails.

```
Error: Cannot read non-required field 'fooid' as required INT64.
```

This is a simplified version of the query to demonstrate the issue, it would be selecting more columns from both foo and bar.

```
SELECT foo.foo_id AS foo
FROM `bar.bar*` AS bar_alias
LEFT JOIN bar.foo_map foo ON (bar_alias.fooid = foo.foo_id)
WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN  '20170206' AND '20170208')
```

I've looked at a number of answers including [BigQuery IF field exists THEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276601/bigquery-if-field-exists-then), but can't see how to use them in conjunction with a `JOIN` or when the tables without the column are not known.

Comment: How are you expecting to read a missing REQUIRED field as if it was present?

Comment: I was expecting for the query to return nulls for `bar*.fooid` and `foo.*` where the field is missing.

Comment: That's not how REQUIRED works, though. One option would be to create an empty table that matches the suffix where the fields are NULLABLE. If that one is used to determine how to read the other matched tables, you'll get NULL instead of an error.

Comment: Ok so I would create a new table `bar_empty` and perform a `UNION` with `bar*`, could you provide an of how to join with `bar_empty`?

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how this can arise, and how to fix it by using a reference schema from an empty table where the column/field is `NULLABLE`. Suppose I have the following two tables:

```
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
  "CREATE TABLE tmp_elliottb.bar20180328 (y STRING) AS SELECT 'bar';"

$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
  "CREATE TABLE tmp_elliottb.bar20180329 " \
  "(x INT64 NOT NULL, y STRING) AS SELECT 1, 'foo';"
```

Column `x` has the `NOT NULL` attribute in the second table, but the column is missing from the first table. I get an error when I try to use a table wildcard:

```
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
  "SELECT * FROM \`tmp_elliottb.bar*\` " \
  "WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180301' AND '20180329';"
Waiting on <job id> ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
Error in query string: Error processing job '<job id>': Cannot read non-required field 'x' as required INT64.
Failure details:
- query: Cannot read non-required field 'x' as required INT64.
```

This makes sense--I said that `x` is `NOT NULL`, but the `bar20180328` table doesn't have the column. Now if I create a new table that matches the `*` expansion, but where the column doesn't have `NOT NULL`:

```
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
  "CREATE TABLE tmp_elliottb.bar_empty (x INT64, y STRING);"
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
  "SELECT * FROM \`tmp_elliottb.bar*\` " \
  "WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180301' AND '20180329';"
...
+------+-----+
|  x   |  y  |
+------+-----+
|    1 | foo |
| NULL | bar |
+------+-----+
```

I get results instead of an error. In your case, you need to create a table with the expected schema called `bar_empty`, for example, but where none of the fields/columns that are missing for other tables have a `NOT NULL` attribute.

With that said, I would strongly recommend using a partitioned table instead, if possible. Among other benefits, partitioned tables are much nicer to work with because they have a consistent schema across all days.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I am assume that works because `bar*` matches all tables first and then `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN` restricts and excludes `bar_empty`.  I will take a look at partitioned tables but I am working with 2-3 years worth of data, the performance benefits do look handy.