# Cannot read non-required field as required STRUCT Field in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

We are running our etl incrementally on ga_sessions table partitioned by date, and for one particular day etl fails with this error ** Cannot read non-required field as required STRUCT Field: trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.targetingCriteria**.

This failure is just for that particular day alone, and works for rest of the days. Not sure, what is the error all about and is there a way, where I can ignore those records or find those ?

Attaching the schema information along with sample query,

[image]

Below query works for other days.
[image]

Failure when 16th November is included.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wildcard tables and differences in table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558833/wildcard-tables-and-differences-in-table-columns)

Comment: Hello @SergeyGeron the table in BQ is partitioned by date, and hence there is no difference in schema.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data that will be helpful to reproduce the error?